# Is there a Google Adsense widget that can display ads based on site search?

Tags: adsense

Can I display google adsense ads on my site based on a user's search term on my website? I'm not using google search on my site, so I'd need to be able to pass the search term to google through the adsense widget's initialization code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm a bit late about this, but I'm actually working in something that you described in your question, and I found this link that could help you in your development:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search-ads/docs/implementation-guide

Using Javascript you can specify some keywords and Adsense search advertisements that fit with them.